# *NIX CLI: Filter, Query XML Attribute and Display

Tags: xml, unix, xpath, command-line-interface

Given the file:

```
/// @file test.xml
<xml-fragment>
  <string name="foo" value="bar"/>
</xml-fragment>
```

the path `xml-fragment/string` and the attribute&value `name="foo"` to filter on, and the attribute `value` to query on, how *should* I get `"bar"`?

Using `xmlstarlet`, I have this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/xml-fragment/string[attribute::name="foo"]' \
                  -v 'attribute::bar' test.xml
```

which appears to work, but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

I don't even require using `xmlstarlet`; I previously tried `xmllint`, `xsltproc`, and `xpath`, but couldn't get those to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is "better", but you could just use `-v` with the entire xpath. You could also use the `@` [abbreviated syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev).

**Example** (tested in windows; quotes might need to be changed)

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/xml-fragment/string[@name='foo']/@value" test.xml
```

Any of the other tools you listed should work as well. If you're just getting a value, `xsltproc` might be overkill. As long as you're [not using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), you should be ok.

Comment: Ah, see,I didn't even think I could trail the "queried" attribute 'value' after "filtering" for 'name="foo"'; I just assumed it had to be a nested element-name.